# Is std::string inferior to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, stdstring, qstring

A colleague of mine claims that the implementation and especially the memory management of `std::string` is inferior to that of the `QString` in the Qt library. What aspects of the `std::string` could this refer too?

Comment: Your buddy is wrong afaik. `QString` is UTF16 and uses 2 bytes per character. `std::string` is single byte per char and usually used for utf8; although it's not automatically utf8. It's more efficient memorywise. QString is re-entrant for most functions and doesn't utilise "moving" as in C++11 as far as I am aware.

Comment: std:string is not a single implementation. There are (maybe not any more) std:string implementations which use copy-on-write like QString.

Comment: Such a statement is pointless. While `QString` is part of Qt, a concrete library, `std::string` is part of a particular *specification* of a library. You can only assess a particular implementation of that specification. The public interface of `QString`, as to memory management, is not sufficiently different from that of `std::string`; so, `std::string` *can* be implemented at least as well as `QString`.

Comment: @adrianm `std::string` COW is no longer allowed since C++11, so such implementations are dying out.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Would the question make more sense if it said Qt vs. gcc implementation of std::string?

Comment: @Martin, actually, as others have said (and I had forgot when I was writing my comment), `QString` uses copy-on-write approach (COW). C++98 allowed for COW, and there were implementations that used it. C++11 no longer allows for COW, so, if you consider only C++11-compliant implementations, the question makes sense as it is.

Comment: I believe gcc's std::string implementation still uses COW for compatibility reasons, but they have another string class, which is c++11 complient.

Comment: Btw.: I'd really like to here your colleague's answer to your question.

Comment: You cannot say that one is inferior to another one. They are just very different implementations each is suitable for a different use case. `QString` matches very well to the rest of Qt ecosystem (many types are implicitly shared, `QString` is no exception) but it does not make sense to be used out of Qt. I suppose you are working on a Qt application, then my basic recommendation would be to use `QString` unless you have a **very good** reason to do otherwise. And no, do not replace `QString`s to `std::string`s just because you **think** you will automtically get better performance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Regarding memory management, `QString` uses copy-on-write, which is now explicitly forbidden in the C++ standard library. But there is a reason for that. The copy-on-write idiom performs worse in multi-threaded environment as it requires synchronization. [This article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/optimizations.htm) discusses the problems in more details.

Implementations of `std::string` on the other hand typically use small-string-optimization (SSO) to avoid any dynamic memory allocation for small strings. That is the current state of the art for strings.

Comment: `uses copy-on-write, which is now explicitly forbidden` AFAIU copy on write is forbidden for `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

With the memory management, you'll have to decide what is better for your application. But one place where QString clearly shines in contrast to std::string, is the unicode support. QString stores an UTF-16 encoded string internally, while std::string is encoding agnostic. This often makes it much simpler to use QString rather then std::string when you have to deal with user-supplied multi-byte encoded strings.